# Dynamically route the request to a origin in amazon lambda@edge

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I have two buckets `Bucket A` which is a primary bucket and `Bucket B` is a secondary bucket.

I have a cloudfront distribution which has the `Origin group` with both the bucket.

My lambda function will read my API and extract the file path to render.

Is there a way I can design the lambda@edge function which can check which bucket has the requested file and use that origin group dynamically?

Comment: Just to confirm, you have an origin for each s3 bucket?

Comment: I have two buckets. I have created a distribution and two origin groups for these buckets. Yes an origin for each s3 bucket

Answer (score 0):

The solution you're looking for is as follows:

- Create a Lambda@Edge function for the origin request behaviour.
- When triggered use SDK to do a check in one of the buckets to check if its there.
- If it is then update the origin/path in the request to become the correct destination.

By calling the [head-object](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3api/head-object.html) command against the first bucket you can verify the object exists there.

It would look similar to this pseudocode

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    request = event['Records'][0]['cf']['request']"
    key = //Code to get the key path from request
    try:
        s3_client.head_object(Bucket='string', Key=key)
    except ClientError as e:
        return request

    request.origin.s3.domainName = \\Insert domain name here
    return request
```

An in depth tutorial can be found [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/dynamically-route-viewer-requests-to-any-origin-using-lambdaedge/).

Comment: I know the steps, how to design the lambda function in python?

Comment: I've added some pseudocode, you'd need to tweak it for your personal requirements

Comment: so I need to check for each bucket separately?

Comment: There's no request to check multiple buckets at once, however, assuming you're using 2 s3 buckets check one and then default to the other

Comment: hey can you help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62278441/how-to-extract-bearer-token-in-using-boto3-python-3-8-in-cloudfront-request-and i am kind of stuck