# How to extract bearer token in using boto3 python 3.8 in cloudfront request and use it in another query

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-edge

How can I extract the bearer token in incoming cloudfront request and use it in another get request.

```
curl -X GET \
  https://domain/api/files/7d0ab8ef-9061-4458--de79a2c9e436 \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer eTA' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: token'
```

use the bearer token as jwt in the following request

```
 in phython domain.com/service/api/files/7d0ab8ef-9061-4458--de79a2c9e436
```

which gives me the following response :

https://domain/file-service/api/files/7d0ab8ef-9061-4458-b97a-de79a2c9e436

```
{
    "id": "7d0ab8ef-9061-4458-b97a-de79a2c9e436",
    "uploadId": "-9b68-44bd-864a-cd9a40d601ba",
    "consumerId": "-97d1-11ea-bb37-0242ac130002",
    "metadata": {
        "fileName": "somefile.docx",
        "fileSize": 1000,
        "mimeType": "application/msword"
    },
    "objectKey": "2020-04-31/ju-28fc-4d7c-b086-66c15eb311e7.docx",
    "status": "PENDING"
}
```

My lambda code looks like this

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    request = event['Records'][0]['cf']['request']
    print(request['headers'])
    print(response)
```

Comment: At what point does the secondary request happen?

Comment: after immediately after fetching the bearer token, there will be  a second get  request that will give me the json response

Comment: OK, and before it reaches the origin endpoint?

Comment: yes before reaching the origin point,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would add this as a Lambda@Edge function for the viewer request event.

The Lambda@Edge would look like the following

```
import json
import requests

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    request = event['Records'][0]['cf']['request']
    print (request)
    print(request['headers'])
    print(request['origin']['s3']['domainName'])
    token = request['headers']['cookie'][0]['value'].partition("=")[2]
    print (token)
    print(type(request['uri']))
    cosumer_id = request['uri'].rpartition('/')[-1]
    print (cosumer_id)

    #Take the token and send it somewhere
    token_response = requests.get(url = 'https://url/api/files/'  + cosumer_id, headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}) 

    print (token_response.request)
    print (token_response)
    print (token_response.text)
    data = token_response.json() 
    objectKey = data["objectKey"]
    print (objectKey)


    return request
```

Assuming you're using the requests library you would be able to retrieve the response like this

```
object = token_response.objectKey
```

Comment: How can I test this code, if I run on lambda by just clicking on test, it gives me error

Comment: Which error? You'll need an example event to test it: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-event-structure.html

Comment: I have added one more thing to my question, how can I fetch the object key from my second request objectKey

Comment: also we have imported the requests module still getting error   "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'requests'",

Comment: How about `from botocore.vendored import requests`?

Comment: yes that works for requests error. Also the cloud formation request we received will take the jwt token and will fetch json response. How it can be done dynamicallly

Comment: Can you expand on that?

Comment: do you know if we can change the origin of a request in lambda@edge

Comment: You can indeed, you can change this in the "Origin Request" event. If you check here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-event-structure.html#example-origin-request you'll notice the origin section :)

Comment: I am able to fetch the domain name and I have the key, how can I return the make the change then return the object. any clue? I am kinda stuck